# Does Retaliation counts on blocked / mitigated damage?

Tags: guild-wars-2

As a guardian, I have some skills that might grant me [retaliation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Retaliation), which is very good against burst classes.

The question is, if I "Block" ([Aegis](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Aegis) for example) an attack, will the other player still be dealt the damage that would have damaged me?

The wiki link says it does, but I'm not sure about it:

> Retaliation does not reduce damage taken by the affected player, but damages anyone   who hits them (even if the hit doesn't actually inflict damage; for example, if it is blocked).

Comment: I think you answered your own question. The quote you have says retaliation will fire if an attack is blocked.

Comment: "The wiki link says it does, but i'm not sure about this."

I haven't tested, and since wiki is sort of "not trusworthy" in some points, i would like to know if someone actually managed to test it. I'm not at home now, otherwise i would test it myself on mobs

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins I'd trust the wiki. The GW2 wiki is one of the best ones I've ever seen.

Comment: @Fluttershy can't hurt to verify though.

Comment: @Fluttershy as you see, Wiki was Incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, Retaliation does not trigger on blocked damage**

It would seem that the wiki is incorrect in this case. To test this, I had an enemy attack my guardian who had both Aegis (from Virtue of Courage) and Retaliation (from Save Yourselves!) active. The first hit, which used up Aegis, didn't cause a damage number to pop up. Only after Aegis was gone did Retaliation start causing damage numbers to appear when the enemy attacked.

Here's a video of my test (HD and fullscreen highly recommended):

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to record a video of your research

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins You're welcome :-)